# Error creating AIR file: Could not generate timestamp: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I've been trying to export a release build from Flash Builder and I'm getting the error:

[image]

The error message is:

> Error creating AIR file: Could not generate timestamp: Remote host
>   closed connection during handshake

**Update:**
I found this [post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/108004) and it says it uses https://timestamp.geotrust.com/tsa to get a timestamp. I visited this URL in the browser and received a 404 - Page not found.

**Update 2:**
It looks like the timestamp [site](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9052698#9052698) has been down for a few days now.

**Update 3:**
It looks like geotrust switched to TLS 1.2 which breaks Flash Builder. Here is Adobe's response [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9052851#9052851):

> Thanks for reporting the issue. We investigated and found that
>   timestamp.geotrust.com has recently disabled TLS 1.0 (see comments on
>   http://downornotworking.com/timestamp.geotrust.com/), and hence please
>   try upgrading to Java 1.8 on your machine where ADT (a component in
>   AIR SDK which is based on Java) packaging takes place.

OK. I've read [here](https://discuss.as3lang.org/t/running-adobe-flash-builder-on-mac-with-java-7-and-8/453) that there have been compatibility issues with Flash Builder and Java 1.8. Do I install Java 1.8? How do I do that with Flash Builder?

I'm running Flash Builder 4.7 on Mac OS X 10.11

Comment: Are you no FB4?

Comment: I'm using Flash Builder 4.7

Comment: FB 4.7 on Windows here, and as far as I can tell I was already using Java 1.8. Still getting the error.

Comment: I read somewhere that someone is able choose another timestamp site using the flag `-tsa other.timestamp.site`. I'll see if I can find it. I don't remember if you this works in FB as a compiler flag or if you have to switch to using Ant which I don't want to do. The export dialog in FB handles all of export process for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good article on how setup Flash Builder for Java 7/8

[Running Adobe Flash Builder on Mac with Java 7/8](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2016/09/running-adobe-flash-builder-on-mac-with-java-78.html)

I am recreating the steps here just in case the link goes offline

> Steps to follow
>
> ```
> Set your JAVA_HOME to Java 7 or Java 8 as per the correct paths on your machine.
>
> export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
> export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> Open JVM’s Info.plist at $JAVA_HOME/../Info.plist and add the highlighted lines to JVMCapabilities array:arrays
> Create a symlink for libjvm.dylib as follows:
>
> sudo mkdir –p /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries
> sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
> ```
>
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
>
> ```
> Note: Correct the version number (in jdk1.7.0_79.jdk) path in the above example to make it point to the correct path on your machine.
> Set java.library.path by adding the following lines at the end of “/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/Adobe Flash Builder
> ```
>
> 4.7.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.ini”.
>
> -Djava.library.path=../../../eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs_4.7.0.349722/os/macosx/:../../../eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.7.0.349722/os/macosx/:../../../eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flexbuilder.utils.osnative_4.7.0.349722/os/macosx/
>
> Restart your machine and launch Flash Builder. Possible error
>
> If you are trying to launch Flash Builder on Mac OS 10.12 and you see
>   an error such as:
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Application
>   "com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.FlashBuilderApplication" could not
>   be found in the registry. The applications available are:
>   org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.ant.ui.antRunner,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild,
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench,
>   org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate,
>   org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer.  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
>
> Locate a directory named “p2” at /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder
>   4.7/ and delete it. Flash Builder should now launch.

Answer (score 1):

This fix worked for me with FlashBuilder 4.7 on windows.

Make sure JDK 1.8 is installed normally.

Remove (rename) the JDK1.6 folder that ships with FlashBuilder:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\jre
```

I renamed it to `jre-removed-to-force-java1.8`, but whatever.

Comment: Do you have Mac Sierra installed or did you upgrade Java manually?

Answer (score 1):

For me this solution worked from Phendrax on this page: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2218793

*After installing Java 1.8,
Go to "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)" (or your Flash Builder installation directory) and rename the folder "jre" to something else (like "_jre"),
Then go to your Java 1.8 installation directory (for me it's "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101"),
And copy the "jre" folder from your Java 1.8 directory to your Flash Builder directory*

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, i solved this with our ant build.xml by adding a "-tsa" arg to the adt java task

```
<!-- Load properties -->
<property file="${basedir}${file.separator}build${file.separator}build.properties" />

<!-- ADT launch -->
<java jar="${flexsdk.adt}" fork="true" failonerror="true" maxmemory="1024m">
    <arg line="-package" />
    <arg line="-keystore ${project.certificate}" />
    <arg line="-storetype pkcs12" />
    <arg line="-storepass ${project.storepass}" />
    <arg line="-tsa ${adt.tsa}" />
    <arg line="-target bundle" />
    <arg line="${buildconfig.path}" />
    <arg line="${buildconfig.path}/${project.name}-app.xml" />
    <arg line="-C ${buildconfig.path} ${project.name}.swf" />
</java>
```

With our build.properties file using the following adt.tsa value

```
adt.tsa = http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp
```